# Angular 2 | How to set Uppercase when form is submitted

Tags: javascript, angular

How to set value to uppercase when form is submitted?

I try to use .toUpperCase() method but it's not working. is their some form validation to auto uppercase value when form is submitted?

here's my below codes.

component.html

```
<div class="form-group input-holder">
    <label class="col-lg-2">Description</label>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <small [ngClass]="{'prompterror': storageForm.controls.description.valid || storageForm.controls.description.pristine}">
         *required
        </small>
        <input type="text" class="input-field" placeholder="Description" formControlName="description" ngModel>
    </div>
</div>
```

component.ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';

import { Storage } from '../shared/storage.model';
import { StorageEntryService } from '../storage.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-storageentry',
    templateUrl: './storageentry.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./storageentry.component.css'],
})
export class StorageentryComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

    storageForm: FormGroup;

    constructor(private storageEntryService: StorageEntryService) {}

    private initForm() {
        let storageDescription = '';

        if (this.editButton) {
            const storage = this.storageEntryService.getStorage(this.storageId)
            storageDescription = storage.description;
        }

        this.storageForm = new FormGroup({
            'description': new FormControl(storageDescription, Validators.required)
        })
    }
}
```

Submit function

```
onSubmit(){
// Switching for Add Button and Edit Button
if (this.editButton) {
  this.storageEntryService.updateStorage(this.storageIdIndex, this.storageForm.value);
  this.editButton = false;
}else{
  this.storageEntryService.addStorage(this.storageForm.value);
}
this.storageForm.reset();
```

}

Comment: you want to allow user to type small character but it should be visible to him in uppercase ???

Comment: I don't see any code for the submit and on the other hand what is the purpose of initForm(), never used.

Comment: initForm() is initialize when edit button is click. it's for edit purposes. ill update my codes

Comment: @mayur yes, or it is also ok to just show all uppercase when they input value in input box.

Comment: @Jydon Mah, initForm() is private so it should not be accessible from the HTML. From your code I see that's reset() is called on submit and not initForm(). It's not relevant to your question but still you can have incoherences.

Comment: @mayur i called that initForm() on ngOnInit() {  } and

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a directive to handle this scenario

```
  <input type="text" change />
```

Directive must have the below keyup event handled

```
@HostListener('keyup') onKeyUp() {
    this.el.nativeElement.value=this.el.nativeElement.value.toUpperCase();
     console.log(this.el.nativeElement.value )

    }
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/RRg4wacuzlDpiyjjXeyK?p=preview)